# How to invoke Animate of an expression that cannot accept the Animate's iterator?

Tags: series-expansion

I want to plot the power series expansion of `sin x` for several `n` (the `Animate` iterator) as follows.

```
Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]] // Plot[#, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] & // 
 Animate[#, {n, 1, 10}] &
```

Unfortunately, `Series` cannot accept variable `n`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workes

```
Animate[Plot[
    Evaluate@Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], {n,
     1, 10, 1}]
```

It seems, Series only gets the n in Animate, if you wrap Animate around Plot/Series.

```
Animate[Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]] // 
   Plot[#, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] &, {n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

Second issue is, that n in Series and therefore in Animate have to be discret integer values.

Comment: Please kindly explain a bit about what the problem was and how it was solved.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity the problem is that you first want to obtain a series with n terms for which $n$ is not defined yet, then `Plot` (nothing to plot), and finally, `Animate` (nothing to animate).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ListAnimate[
 Plot[#, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] & /@ 
  Table[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}] // Normal, {n, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]

Have fun!